# How do I get this value from NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, json, nsmutablearray, nsarray

this is a fairly simple question.

I am using a web service in my app, and the server returns a JSON string to communitcate with the app.

Here is an example response:

```
{
    repsonse =     {
        message = "Message";
        "response_id" = X;
    };
}
```

Using objective-c I want to be able to get what "response_id" is but I am unsure on how to do this.

Here is my code:

```
NSMutableArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
// Get json value
NSLog(@"%@", json);

if([json[@"response"][@"response_id"] isEqualToString:@"1"]){
    return YES;
}else{
    return NO;
}
```

Each time the isStringEqualTo method returns false.

Could somebody help me?

Thanks,

Peter

Comment: First off, the root of this `json` is a dictionary, not an array. Change `json` to `NSMutableDictionary`. Second, `isEqualToString:` returns a `BOOL` so it can't return `null`. Third - are you sure the value of `response_id` is string and not a number?

Comment: I meant 'false', not null, sorry. I will try change the NSMutableArray to a dictionary and post back :)

Comment: Would response be an array or dictionary?

Comment: Look at the JSON - what do you think it is?

Comment: Why not log the value of `json[@"response"][@"response_id"]` so you can see what's going on? Also: what rmaddy said, except that it should be `NSDictionary*` rather than `NSMutableDictionary*` because you haven't specified mutable containers in your options.

Comment: I have updated that. When I log json[@"response"][@"response_id"] it returns null

Comment: Also, I will keep change it to NSMutableDictionary because in the future there will be more objects in the dictionary.

Comment: Paste the real JSON. The JSON in your question has a key of "repsonse", not "response".

Comment: It was a spelling mistake. If you h=post that as an answer I will accept it. Repsonse was meant to be response! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. `json` needs to be declared as an `NSDictionary`, not `NSMutableArray` since the JSON root is a dictionary, not an array. And you get back an immutable dictionary, not a mutable one.
2. The JSON has a key of "repsonse", not "response".